# remote desktop: the app on the remote machine is confusing the controller's hostname with its own hostname

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, remote-access, remote-control, remote-connection

I have 2 machines A, B, both run Windows OS.  A is my work machine, B is a server on which I have already installed SQLServer. Now I want to install another software on B which runs on top of the SQLServer.
I remote connect to B from A.
Then on the remote desktop, I start the installer, along the installation process, there's a step where I can configure which server to connect to.  normally B's hostname is entered automatically to the hostname field.
The issue I'm having is, when I get to that step, A's hostname is entered automatically instead of B's, and even if I manually correct it to 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' or B's hostname, the installer still cannot connect to B's service as if it still try to connect to A.

Theoretically, how does this happen? how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `Automatically detect RD Gateway server settings` selected. This would be why it is picking up the settings from your work machine.

Go to your RDC connection settings, go to the `Advanced` tab, select the `Connect from anywhere settings`

[image: remote desktop]